# How to get matplotlib-type ticks?

Tags: plotting, style, ticks, python, plot-themes

Consider the following plot, obtained with the Python plotting library `matplotlib`:

[image]

Is it possible to get the plot ticks to have this same style in a Mathematica plot? That is, facing outwards? Furthermore, notice also how the first and last ticks are a continuation of the frame, as seen here

[image]

All I have been able to do so far, for random data, was

```
ListLinePlot[RandomReal[2, 30], Frame -> True, FrameTicks -> {{Range[0, 2, .5], None}, {Range[0, 30, 5], None}}]
```

[image]

Now I just need to make the ticks face outwards and fix the frame corners. Any ideas?

PS- I would be happy with just the facing outward solution!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
ListLinePlot[RandomReal[2, 30], Frame -> True, 
 PlotRangePadding -> 0, 
 FrameTicks -> {{{#, #, {0, .02}} & /@ Range[0, 2, .5],None},
   {{#, #, {0, .02}} & /@ Range[0, 30, 5], None}}]
```

[image]

**See:** [`Ticks >> Details`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Ticks.html)

[image]

**Update:** ***"What if I want to maintain Mathematica's automatic tick locations"***

You can post-process plot output to reverse the third parts of tick specs:

```
ClearAll[reflectTicks]

reflectTicks[s_ : 1] :=  Show[#, 
   FrameTicks -> 
     ReplaceAll[{a_, b_, c : {_, _}, d___} :> {a, b, 2 Reverse@c, d}]@
     Last@First@AbsoluteOptions[#, FrameTicks]] &;


reflectTicks[2] @
 ListLinePlot[RandomReal[2, 30], Frame -> True, 
  FrameTicks -> {{Automatic, None}, {Automatic, None}}]
```

[image]

**Update 2:**

A more convenient way to change the direction of ticks using a custom tick function:

```
tickFunc = MapAt[Reverse, {All, 3}]@*
   Charting`ScaledTicks[{Identity, Identity}, "TicksLength" -> {.03, .02}];

ListLinePlot[RandomReal[2, 30], Frame -> True, 
 FrameTicks -> {{tickFunc, None}, {tickFunc, None}}]
```

[image]

You can specify the number of major and minor ticks using the last argument of `tickFunc`:

```
ListLinePlot[RandomReal[2, 30], Frame -> True, 
 FrameTicks -> {{tickFunc, None}, {tickFunc[##, {8, 5}] &, None}}]
```

[image]

Comment: What if I want to maintain Mathematica's automatic tick locations (labeled or not) but simply make them face outwards?

Comment: @samwolfe, please see the update.

Comment: thank you! Also, I'm not too sure why this question was closed as "off-topic". Is it because this should be standard knowledge? Is it related to the fact that it's a Python-inspired question? It's not clear to me, but do you have any suggestions on how to edit it?

Comment: @samwolfe, I think the close votes were  because the solution is _"easily found in the documentation."_   If you edit your question adding the additional requirement (maintaining automatic ticks and tick labels)  the question is likely to get reopen votes.

Comment: Still on this question, when I use a different `AspectRatio`, I sometimes get overlapping of the ticks with its legends. Try, for example, this `ListLinePlot[RandomReal[{0, 1}, 1000], AspectRatio -> 1/6, 
 Frame -> True, ImageSize -> 800, PlotRangePadding -> 0, 
 FrameTicks -> {{tickFunc, None}, {tickFunc, None}}]`. Is there a way to increase the spacing between ticks and their labels? Thanks